# Is it possible to make template specialization for zero template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's suppose I have a class like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
  int n = 1;
  S(T t) : n(t) {};
  S() = default;
};
```

Is it possible to change something so that it would be possible to instantiate `S` with no template arguments in case if I want to use the default constructor like that `S s {};`?

The best thing I came up with is to assign some bogus default value to the template argument so that it becomes optional:

```
#include <iostream>

struct default_ {};

template <typename T = default_>
struct S {
  int n = 1;
  S(T t) : n(t) {};
  S() = default;
};


int main() {
  S<int> s1 {10};
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s1.n << std::endl;
  S s2 {};
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s2.n << std::endl;
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/RegalCoolDeal

Comment: You can already use the default constructor, since you declared it default. Your question needs clarity. You could just default the template parameter to anything. Or use a partial template specialization.

Comment: The question is clear and challenging. See my answer below ;)

Comment: Why are you initializing the integer `n` with an arbitrary type?

Comment: @jjramsey, it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `T` is used only for the constructor, you don't need to template the whole class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  int n = 1;

  template <typename T>
  S(T t) : n(t) {};

  S() = default;
};

int main() {
  S s1 {10};
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s1.n << std::endl;
  S s2 {};
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s2.n << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not allowing to compile the line ```S<int> s1 {10};```, which was in the original question and part of the requirement IMHO.

Comment: @Hack06. I don't see that requirement anywhere in the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, it's up to you, but I don't take the question out of the context. I just pointed out the fact that others may have overlooked.

Answer (score 12):

You might specialize S for void and create a CTAD https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct S {
  int n = 1;
  S(T t) : n(t) {}; // no default
};

template <>
struct S<void> {
  int n = 1;
  S() = default;  // only default
};

// CTAD calls to constructor S() will instantiate as S<void> 
template<typename... T> S() -> S<void>;   

int main() {
  S<int> s1 {10};
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s1.n << std::endl;
  S s2 {};  // here CTAD will be trigged
  std::cout << "Value:\n" << s2.n << std::endl;
}
```

A link to cppinsights may help understand what and where things are being instantiated: https://cppinsights.io/s/8f0f4bf6

Comment: Thanks! This seems better to me. Just to note that CTAD requires C++17 to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `enable_if` to match zero template args as well.

This isn't code that matches your specific use case, but is an example you can work from:

```
template <typename... Args>
static typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) == 0), bool>::type MatchesZeroArgsOverload();
```